# Akka HelloWorld Not Compiling :-(

Tags: java, exception, akka

Been trying to get to grips with AKKA over the last few days and the Actor Model I get, I get communication through messages etc but I'm dammed if I can get just a simple HelloWorld project to compile. Here's the single helloWorld.java file... I have included both classes(Actors) in here...

```
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;

public class helloWorld extends UntypedActor {

  @Override
  public void preStart() {
    // create the greeter actor
    final ActorRef greeter =
        getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Greeter.class), "greeter");
    // tell it to perform the greeting
    greeter.tell(Greeter.Msg.GREET, getSelf());
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object msg) {
    if (msg == Greeter.Msg.DONE) {
      // when the greeter is done, stop this actor and with it the application
      getContext().stop(getSelf());
    } else unhandled(msg);
  }
}

public class Greeter extends UntypedActor {

  public static enum Msg {
    GREET, DONE;
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object msg) {
    if (msg == Msg.GREET) {
      System.out.println("Hello World!");
      getSender().tell(Msg.DONE, getSelf());
    } else unhandled(msg);
  }

}
```

Here's the command I'm using in Terminal (Ubunut)...

```
java -classpath $AKKA_HOME/lib/scala-library.jar:$AKKA_HOME/lib/akka/akka-actor_2.10-2.2.1.jar:$AKKA_HOME/lib/akka/config-1.0.2.jar akka.Main helloWorld
```

And here's the exception I'm getting...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: helloWorld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:67)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:66)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(DynamicAccess.scala:66)
    at akka.Main$.main(Main.scala:32)
    at akka.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Can anyone offer any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really mean its not compiling? I think its compiling but not running.

Comment: Yes sorry, you're right, using 'Boris the Spiders'  java -classpath $AKKA_HOME/lib/scala-library.jar:$AKKA_HOME/lib/akka/akka-actor_2.10-2.2.1.jar:$AKKA_HOME/lib/akka/config-1.0.2.jar akka.Main helloWorld.java do; I get "you need to provide exactly one argument: the class of the application supervisor"?

Comment: you forgot to pass to akka.Main the argument of the Actor to use: e.g. 
java -classpath <all JARs> akka.Main your.package.name.HelloWorld

Comment: @user1974297 When I got the _"you need to provide exactly one argument: the class of the application supervisor actor"_ its was because there was NO entry point such as **'static main'** method. In my case I accidentally named the entry method **'Main'** with capital 'M' which caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The class path you are using contains only the dependency jars, not your helloWorld.class (which you of course also need to compile). If you use

```
javac -classpath $AKKA_HOME/lib/scala-library.jar:$AKKA_HOME/lib/akka/akka-actor_2.10-2.2.1.jar:$‌​AKKA_HOME/lib/akka/config-1.0.2.jar helloWorld.java
```

then you will find it in the current working directory, which means that you just add ":." to the class path to make it work. Another recommendation is to avoid the default package and always put your classes into a named package like `package tsume`.